# set style only for elements are inside a specific div

Tags: css

I just wanna apply my custom style into the elements which are inside a specific div. I mean there are many elements with the same class all over the page and I want only apply these custom CSS to elements are inside a div with the data attr like `div data-some-feature=...` and not apply to the rest

```
     <div class="row" data-language>
      <section class="posts by-tags show-grid" data-language>
           <div class='right a'>a</div>
             <div class="row">';
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 m-right">
                 <div class="a">
                   <h6>apple</h6>
                   <p>some text...</p>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
    </section>
      </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <section .....>
         ......
     </section>
   </div>

<style>
   div[data-dictionary-language].posts {
     //some style
     }
</style>
```

I want to use only div[data-dictionary-language] once and then apply my custom CSS like below:

```
   <style>
     div[data-dictionary-language]{
      .tags{
         //some style only apply to all elements are inside the specific div
        }
      .posts{
        //some style only apply to all elements are inside the specific div
       }
    }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, try like so:

```css
/*     ___________ select the div with data-language attribute 
       |           ______ note the space here
       |          |    ________ select child of div[data-language] with class posts
 ______|________  | __|__                                                          */
div[data-language] .posts {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" data-language>
      <section class="posts by-tags show-grid" data-language>
           <div class='right a'>a</div>
             <div class="row">';
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 m-right">
                 <div class="a">
                   <h6>apple</h6>
                   <p>some text...</p>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
    </section>
      </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <section .....>
         ......
     </section>
   </div>
```

Comment: I know that but my problem is I have to write `div[data-language] . posts  div[data-language] .right` for every style and so on . I want only write `div[data-language]` once and inside the code I simply write `.posts{//some style}` and so on

Comment: @steven that's not CSS then you are talking about Scss there you can do that. At the end though it will be transformed back to CSS for the browsers to handle it.

Comment: and @steven even though you say you know it how you are using the ` . ` between attributes and class names like what you are in your code and comment it will not work! cause you have the spaces at the wrong place